# Android NumberPicker optimization

Tags: android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I need to create two NumberPicker, one with 5000 elements, and the other one with 20000 elements.
I set up this two pickers at startup of my app (inside splashscreen activity), but generation requires a lot of time (more or less 10/15 seconds).
There's a way to optimize this process and reduce generation time?

this is how i initialize pickers:

```
        picker = new NumberPicker(context);
        picker.setLayoutParams(
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        pickerValues = new String[20000];
        for (int i = 0; i < pickerValues.length; i++)
            pickerValues[i] = i;

        picker.setMinValue(1);
        picker.setMaxValue(20000);
        picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        picker.setDisplayedValues(pickerValues);
        picker.setValue(1);
        picker.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

then i change color of picker (it's showed into a Custom dialog)

```
final int count = picker.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = picker.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof EditText) {
                try {
                    Field selectorWheelPaintField = picker.getClass()
                            .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                    selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                    ((Paint) selectorWheelPaintField.get(picker))
                            .setColor(MyApp.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                    ((EditText) child).setTextColor(MyApp.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                    picker.invalidate();
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {

                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you post some code snippets to get more clear about your problem?

Comment: i've edited with code @pRaNaY